# Perl framework for report - creating variable dynamically

Tags: perl, csv, dynamic

I am trying to design a framework for Perl where sql file will be kept in a separate file. The Perl script should read the SQL file and identify how many columns are selected and it should iterate the output of the SQL query and write them as CSV file. Initially I would like to start from simple query like:

```
select col1, col2 from table1;
```

So the Perl script should iterate the SQL output and create CSV file like below:

```
val1a,val1b

val2a,val2b

val3a,val3b
```

The problem I am facing is I do NOT know how to create the number of variables dynamically. Say if there are 2 columns in the SQL query I must have 2 variable to store the column values and write it to output file. If there are 3 columns it should be able to create 3 variables without changing the script.

Please advice if there are any Perl external modules which supports this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **[do not want to create dynamic variables](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)**. Instead, you want to use a hash.

If you're not familiar with this concept, please take a look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). For your SQL interaction you should start by reading the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI), specifically [`fetchrow_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref) and [`fetchrow_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref). To write the data to CSV, use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Text::CSV;
use autodie;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
open my $fh, '>', 'output.csv';

my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... );

# write headings
$csv->print($fh, ['val1', 'val2']);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT val1, val2 FROM table1');
$sth->execute;

while (my $res = $dbh->fetchrow_arrayref) {
  $fh->print($fh, $res);
}

close $fh;
```